# Wepack compilation fails with reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am facing errors with a compilation of webpack when running with my react project shown as below:

```
    ERROR in ./src/dispatcher-dev/App.js 17:20
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:20)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    | class App extends Component {
    >   componentDidMount = () => {
    |     // Check the type of browser and add a class accordingly to the body
    |     let browser = (function(){
     @ ./src/dispatcher-dev/index.js 7:0-24 10:36-39
     @ multi ./src/dispatcher-dev/index.js
```

I have included `babel-loader` in my webpack and also the `react-dom` and `prop-types`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: my webpack.config.js looks as below :

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to add a static property in js class.

To use such feature you should add [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) plugin to your babel